# Insert new data only if it does not exist

Tags: php, sqlite

Why is this not working? I am trying to insert new data only if it does not meet with my requirements.

```
$stm= "INSERT INTO `orders` (userid, username, quantity, time, image, uprice, tprice) 
        VALUES
        (:userid, :username, :quantity, :timee, :image, :uprice, :tprice) 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (select username from orders where username=:username and image=:image)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `INSERT .... VALUES` which does not allow a `WHERE` clause, use `INSERT .... SELECT`:

```
$stm= "INSERT INTO `orders` (userid, username, quantity, time, image, uprice, tprice) 
       SELECT :userid, :username, :quantity, :timee, :image, :uprice, :tprice
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (select username from orders where username=:username and image=:image)";
```